# Ajuda em formulário Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Preciso colocar um value nesse `Form`:

```
{{Form::label('genre','Escolha a categoria') }}
{{Form::select('genre',$options->getGenresClassificados(),null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
```

Comment: A sua pergunta faltam muitos detalhes, ou seja, não está claro o suficiente!

Comment: esse é resultado <option value="0">ACADEMIA/FITNESS</option> preciso que fique assim <option value="ACADEMIA/FITNESS">ACADEMIA/FITNESS</option> entendeu?

Comment: O que retorna `getGenresClassificados()`?

Comment: categorias <option value="0">ACADEMIA/FITNESS</option>

Comment: preciso que fique assim <option value="ACADEMIA/FITNESS">ACADEMIA/FITNESS</option>

Comment: você precisa corrigir o retorno de `options->getGenresClassificados()` não tem como fazer mais nada por você em relação ao conteúdo frágil da pergunta.

Comment: em html ficaria assim

<select name="genre">
    @foreach($options->getGenresClassificados() as $categoria) 
    <option value= " {{ $categoria }} "> {{$categoria}} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>